# Laravel 8 User roles & Permissions using jetstream

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-8

I am working on a project on laravel 8. 
I am a newbie. Learning and developing a live web application at the same time.

I have used jetstream for authentication. And following that, i have built my other modules.

Now i want to develop the user management. Where i Can create user roles and assign them permissions. Also, apart from role based permissions, there should be permissions overrides to be applied to each user.

I have checked online tutorials on user roles and permissions with a package called spatie.

My questions are:

1. Can i add the user roles and permissions to already existing project? (Asking this because i see the tutorials mentioning to have a fresh install of laravel)
2. Can spatie be used along with jetstream? (There are certain articles which points compatiblity & other issues it creates)

Highly appreciate any pointers to help me go ahead with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. yes you can use roles & permission for an existing project. add table for role, & make a table where you can store the permissions for the role. make the relation between them. implement these on the model where you need them.
2. Yes. Spatie Can be used along with jetstream.

Comment: Thank You for your answer. And sorry for responding back late.
Yup, Managed to get it working right with Jetstream and spatie.